# How to rollback database query if has not saved on the server?

Tags: python, django

I have functionality when I need to save a file on the server and put corresponding record in the database. How can I ensure that either both events happen either none?

For now I have the following logic, but is there a better solution?

```
def handle_uploaded_file(filename, file_content, request):
    # Saves file on the server
    try:
        path_to_file = '{}/{}'.format(settings.REPORTS_FOLDER, filename)
        with open(path_to_file, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in file_content.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
    except IOError:
        raise
    # Saves info about uploaded file in the database
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            new_report = Reports(
                path_to_file=path_to_file,
                document_name=filename,
                author=request.user,
                document_type=request.POST['report_type']
                )
            new_report.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        os.remove(path_to_file)
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def handle_uploaded_file(filename, file_content, request):
    path_to_file = '{}/{}'.format(settings.REPORTS_FOLDER, filename)

    save_file_metadata(filename, path_to_file, request)
    write_file_contents(file_content, path_to_file)


def write_file_contents(file_content, path_to_file):
    try:
        with open(path_to_file, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in file_content.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
    except IOError:
        os.remove(path_to_file)
        raise


def save_file_metadata(filename, path_to_file, request):
    new_report = Reports(
            path_to_file=path_to_file,
            document_name=filename,
            author=request.user,
            document_type=request.POST['report_type']
    )
    new_report.save()
```

The advantage is that you first save the metadata in the database (which can throw as far as I understand your sample). If it does throw, the transaction will not complete and no contents will be stored.

If the OS write throws, the database transaction will not be completed since the exception is re-raised.

The file cleanup, however looks like it needs more work to me to be fully failsafe.